# Excel text to number conversion is incorrect (VBA or manually?)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having an excel workbook mixed with numbers in ‘numbers format’ and ‘text format’ making it not usable for calculations. All numbers has to be in ‘numbers format’.

My issue is when I convert numbers either manually or with a VBA code they convert into the wrong size. Fx. Cells with 1.0554 (one point zero five five four) in text format must be converted into 1,0554 (one commazero five five four) in numbers format, and not converted into 10554 (ten thousand five hundred and fifty-four) in numbers format.

Anyone knows how this can be solved?

My current VBA code is the following, however if the issue can be solved in an easier way without VBA then that is also much appreciated!

```
Sub ConvertTextToNumbers()
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("K2:O" & lastRow)
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) = False And cell.Value <> "" Then
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ",", Application.DecimalSeparator)
        cell.Value = Val(cell.Value)
        If IsError(cell.Value) Then cell.Value = 0
    End If
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then cell.Value = CDbl(cell.Value)
Next cell
```

End Sub

Comment: Do the values come from a CSV file? Do you have access to that file?

Comment: Couple of things **1.** what does `?Application.DecimalSeparator` give in the immediate window? **2.** You do not need to replace both `.` and `,`. If your decimal separator is `,` then you just need 1 line which is `cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)`

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing dots and commas both of them with the same decimal separator.

Probably one of them should be the Thousands Separator. Anyways, try replacing this part:

```
cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ".", Application.DecimalSeparator)
cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ",", Application.DecimalSeparator)
```

With

```
cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, ",", "")
cell.Value = Val(Replace(cell.Value, ".", ","))
```

If you later on need visually to see the dot as a thousands separator, you can do it formatting the cell, but not really needed for calculations.